# What does "I have got a witness 'set up' down the road? "mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

***set up***

The context is a detective telling another detective about the case in an episode of *Wandavision.*

I specifically want to know what does "set up" mean here?[image]

Comment: It means there is a witness ready to talk to us (set up means ready and arranged).

Comment: In this case, it looks like "placed in position"...[see definition # 1 at Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/set_up)

Comment: Ok yosef but the person's missing